# How can I sort the postman arry data response?

Tags: javascript, postman

My postman API is returning data without sorting for the dataset arry. Anyone please help me to write the code to sort it?
Or also can make it by using .find

```
{
    "api_version": "0.1",
    "time_stamp": 1661856020,
    "providerid": 09099,
    "start_timestamp": 1654041600,
    "end_timestamp": 1654214400,
    "value": 1440,
    "fields": [
        "time_stamp",
        "bsp"
    ],
    "dataset": [
        [
            "2022-06-02T00:00:00Z",
            59
        ],
        [
            "2022-06-01T00:00:00Z",
            58
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "your postman API"? AFAIK, Postman is a tool for debugging services.

Comment: I mean using POSTMAN tool, I'm hitting an API end point which is returning the json response without sorting the data. I want to sort the dataset array with test script in postman. I hope you understand now?

Comment: Please elaborate: How shall it look after sorting? And do you want to sort it only in Postman when viewing the response - or shall the server itself return the data sorted already?

Comment: The API will not return response in sorting. so i need help to add some script in POSTMAN tests tab to fetch the response and validate its dataset array data accordingly.

Comment: And how can i validate dataset response with tests script?

Answer (score 0):

Postman is just a debugging tool. It lets you call the API and conveniently inspect its responses by changing various parameters. If you want changed API response, you'll need to make changes to the API.
Second, isn't the dataset array already sorted? -59 is lower than -58, right?

Edit: Updating answer based on comments.

You can try to write a javascript code like this to sort the response.

```js
var object = {
    "api_version": "0.1",
    "time_stamp": 1661856020,
    "providerid": 09099,
    "start_timestamp": 1654041600,
    "end_timestamp": 1654214400,
    "value": 1440,
    "fields": [
        "time_stamp",
        "bsp"
    ],
    "dataset": [
        [
            "2022-06-02T00:00:00Z",
            59
        ],
        [
            "2022-06-01T00:00:00Z",
            58
        ]
    ]
}
 
object.dataset.sort(function(a, b){return a[1] - b[1]});
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Actually, some how we couldn't change API response for sorting. I shared the example now i've modified to make proper example.  POSTMAN allows to users can add scripts in Tests tab to validate the response based on the scripts.

Comment: That test is actually for testing the APIs, it will not change the API response. For example, you can check the response status of the api. https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/

Comment: understood.

Is that possible to add some script in POSTMAN tests tab to fetch the response and validate its dataset array data accordingly? i don't want to validate that by giving hard coded values..